# How can I get the name of the class of the code below with Python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, class

How can I get the class name of this html component using python embedded functions? I have tried  `__getattribute__('class')`.

```
<pre>
div style="display: block;" class="eview-table-empty-msg">
            No records found.
</pre>

x = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div".__getattribute__('class'))))
```

Comment: Is the output you want "eview-table-empty-msg" or "No records found" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH ,"/html/body/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/table/tbody/tr/td[3]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div")))
```

to output subclasses of an element: (for you output "eview-table-empty-msg")

```
print(x.get_attribute('class'))
```

to output text of an element: (for you output "No records found")

```
print(x.text)
```